# Removed AMP for WordPress Plugin and now "/amp" and "?nonamp=1" URLs have infinite self-redirect

Tags: google-search-console, redirects, wordpress, url, amp

Google Search Console(GSC) shows "Page with redirect" errors on my website.  According to GSC, these posts are not indexed. That is fine. But look like the URLs with "/amp" and "?nonamp=1" are still active on my WordPress website. Though these URLs are not indexed, I want to permanently remove them from my website.  Kindly guide me on how to remove these amp URLs.

Note: I have removed the "WP for AMP" plugin a long time ago.

Comment: Thank you Stephen for your time. I wish to mention that my problem is peculiar I think.  My redirecting URL itself loading as is (without redirecting to the correct URL). Here is the link for example.  "https://www.noblehomeremedies.com/dry-skin-remedies?nonamp=1". Please check on this. (this URL is not supposed to exist on my WordPress site as I did remove the "AMP for WP" plugin a long time ago.

Comment: Ah, it redirects to itself.  That is an error.